# How to store a variable in python?

Tags: python, loops

I'm trying to do a count down function in python using a while loop. Basically I want it to count down and up again but I'm running into an issue with storing the initial value.

```
def function(n):
    n = stored
    while stored < 0:
        print stored,
        function(stored-1)
   while stored > 0 & < function:
       print stored
       function(stored+1)
```

What am I missing?

Comment: I guess what you're trying to do is `stored = n` before the first loop starts, right?

Comment: Is it your intention to do this recursively?

Comment: `while stored > 0 & < function:` this is invalid syntax

Comment: In your example, notice that the variable _stored_ doesn't exist. Either you get an error or _stored_ is a global variable. In the latter case, you overwrite the parameter _n_ with whatever is in that global variable.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your function was oddly formatted so I did a bit of a rewrite.

Here you go:

```
def function(n):
    stored  = n
    print(stored)
    while stored > 0:
        stored = stored - 1
        print(stored)
    while stored < n:
        stored = stored + 1
        print(stored)

function(10)
```

Answer (score 1):

This part isn't using the right syntax.

```
 while stored > 0 & < function:
```

I think you mean:

```
 while stored > 0 and stored < function:
```

Note that & is a bitwise operator, which I believe is not what you wanted*.
*Thanks Blckknght and skrrgwasme from the comments

Also, making

```
 n = stored
```

makes n useless as a parameter.
Did you mean

```
 stored = n
```

It would make more sense to me.

Comment: ` while stored > 0 & stored < function:` is syntactically valid, but almost certainly not what is intended. `&` is a bitwise operator and `function` is the name of the function we're running, not something that can be usefully compared against.

Comment: If that is what the OP intended, `while stored > 0 & stored < function' should actually be `while stored > 0 and stored < function'. The single `&` is a bitwise operator, while `and` is the logical operator.

Comment: Thanks, fixed the answer